# App contains icon or button that are not responsive or do not return content in play console for flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

Hi I have the below code for the Flutter app bar, but when publishing it to Play Store I get Google policy violation error "App contains icon or button that is not responsive or do not return content" and the app gets rejected

Issue found: Violation of Broken Functionality policy

How can I fix this

```js
class AppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const AppBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(110);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55, left: 20, right: 20),
      //height: 175,
      //height: 120,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          stops: [0.1, 0.5],
          colors: [
            Color(0xff886ff2),
            Color(0xff6849ef),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              //Container(child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/logo.png', height: 65)),
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      blurRadius: 60,
                      offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/logo.png', height: 65),
              ),
              Text(
                "Good,\n${greeting()}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
              ),
              CircleButton(
                icon: Icons.notifications,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to publish in the Google Play Store but got the error

Comment: Instead of `CircleButton` just use Icon, but is there is no functionality/purpose(as now),  it can be removed ig.